# Is there something that can be applied to electrical connections to prevent rust and corrosion?

Tags: electrical, wiring, rust, corrosion

Another recent question got me thinking about this. 
[Will a ground to the frame work properly if the bolt is powder-coated?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27848/will-a-ground-to-the-frame-work-properly-if-the-bolt-is-powder-coated)

Since I don't have any skill, tools, or ability to powder coat, whats the best way to make a ground connection to the frame or block in a way that will prevent rust or corrosion from forming? Maybe a different way to ask is this: 
Is there a chemical coating or treatment that can be applied to a clean, metal to metal, soldered and crimped ring lug ground connection that will prevent rust or corrosion from breaking the connection? I'm thinking of the screw holding the ring lug and the bare metal beneath it rusting and how to prevent that.

I'm asking in general, but the application would be for a 2000 Toyota Camry with 142k miles on it.

Comment: I use dielectric grease to avoid issues mentioned things: http://www.geeksofcars.com/facts_6802259_dielectric-grease_.html Buy from any auto parts store.

Comment: @racefever How do you use it anyways? Since it's dielectric, you can't really apply it on the contact points themselves, do you just dab it on after tightening the connetion? What if you remove it and want to reassemble, would you have to thoroughly clean it and reapply so it wouldn't get on the contact points? I know it is used on spark plug wires, but as I understand it's just to increase it's voltage resistance and possibly prevent drying out and cracking.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Pretty much like that. Just coat it a little bit and be done with it.

Comment: A tight connection will push oil/grease out of the way and establish a metal to metal contact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general silicone gease applied to the parts before and after assembly is a good way to go. It will be pushed out of the way where you have tight metal to metal contact so it won't cause electrical connection problems. It won't crack up if things move slightly and it won't stop you dismantling and reassembling things if you need to.

Comment: They usually have it in a tube, called dielectric grease.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a spray can of undercoating and spray your connection area with that after your connection is made. Paint works too, but undercoating is somewhat flexible and won't crack like paint will if the connection is subject to any flexing.